# plotting image in a 3D plot, python

Tags: python, image, 3d, matplotlib, patch

I'm looking to plot an image on an arbitrary plan in 3 space. I've used matplotlib for some 3d curve plotting and I've had good luck. Something more specific would be putting 6 different images on a cube and rotating it in space, (this could be done with several plots saved as images). I cannot just rotate the camera, I will have multiple cubes rotate in different directions. I would expect a 3Dplot method that allows me to pick the four corners of an imported image. Were i using MATLAB i would use something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21881-image3) which allows you to plot an image in 3space with the following code:

```
C = rand(8,4)*64;                % a small random image
R = [1 0; 0 1; 0 0];
t = [10-1;20-1;5];
h = image3(C,[R t]); axis equal
view(30,45);
```

I would like to do this with Python.

Comment: You should add some code that you've already tried, and the most important, tell us in what language are you coding...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot definitely deny that this is possible in matplotlib, but it's definitely not the intent of mpl. I'd really propose to use `mayavi` instead.